# Linear Algebra Proof of Injective Function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I'm new in the University and I don't know how to solve this:

Suppose $v$ is a non null element of a vector space $V$ on $\mathbb R$. Show that the function is injection:

$\mathbb R\to V $

$t \mapsto tv$

Sorry for any misspelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $tv = sv$, then $(t-s)v = 0$. As $v \neq 0$ (that is, it is not the null element of $V$), we must have $t - s = 0$, so $tv = sv \Rightarrow t = s$. Therefore, the mapping is injective.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a good introductory book for Linear Algebra?

Comment: Lay's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* is the book my university recommends, but I haven't used it myself so I don't know what it is like.